# Is there a command line mail program for Mac?

Tags: terminal, email

My C++ professor has had us use Terminal for editing code. Is there an app or program that will allow me to send and receive email via Terminal, so I can stay in one window?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This sure takes me back to my university days...

[Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) has still got to be one of the best terminal-based mail clients out there. It's been around longer than I'd like to admit. It's available as a [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) package:

```
> brew info mutt
mutt 1.5.21
http://www.mutt.org/
Depends on: tokyo-cabinet
Not installed
http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/mutt.rb
```

Overall you'll get a much better experience using something like Mutt than you will with something like `mail` because it supports IMAP, POP3 and SMTP -- you don't have to learn sendmail or anything like that to get it to work with your accounts.

You can even use Mutt with Gmail if that's your bag. See [this article for details on setting up Mutt to work with Gmail](https://www.andrews-corner.org/mutt.html).

Pretty colours...

[image: Mutt in action]

Comment: LOL. A down vote. Disgruntled PINE user maybe? Sucks to be stuck in the dark ages of terminal mail programs. :)

Answer (score 13):

For a full fledged terminal based email client that supports most email protocols, I'd suggest using [mutt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutt_%28e-mail_client%29). You can download mutt [from here](http://www.mutt.org/download.html), if you'd like to build from source. [This webpage](http://linsec.ca/Using_mutt_on_OS_X) gives you directions on how to install on OS X.

If you use `homebrew`, then installing is as simple as `brew install mutt` (and similarly for `fink` and `macports`).

Here are a few basic steps to get your `.muttrc` configured:

```
#Set account info
set spoolfile=/var/spool/mail/jdoe #if using IMAP, use imaps://example.com/INBOX
set folder="$HOME/mail"            #if using IMAP, use imaps://example.com/
set imap_user=jdoe
set from='jdoe@example.com'
set realname='John Doe'
set signature="~/.signature"

#Mailbox behaviour
set mail_check=15                  #check for new mail
set timeout=30
set include=yes                    #quote when replying

#Compose/reply/etc...
set editor=vim                     #change to your favourite command line editor  
ignore headers *
unignore headers from to subject date cc
hdr_order from to cc subject date
set fast_reply                     #don't ask for to, subject when replying
unset metoo                        #remove myself from replies
set sort=date-received
```

You can customize these further as you wish, and there are also some useful questions in the `mutt` tag on [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutt) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutt)

Comment: After installing mutt via `homebrew`, I could view my local email (/var/mail/admin), but couldn't delete anything -- mutt kept saying the mailbox was "read-only." Turns out I had to add myself to the `mail` group to be able to delete: `dseditgroup -o edit -u [username] -p -a [username] -t user mail`. Don't know if that happens when installing via other methods, but it sounds like a Darwin thing, so it probably does.

Answer (score 13):

Yes and here is another one called the Alpine Messaging System a.k.a [Alpine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_%28email_client%29). Available from the [University of Washington](http://www.washington.edu/alpine/)

> Alpine is a free software email client developed at the University of Washington.
>   Alpine 1.0 was publicly released on December 20, 2007.
>   The name "Alpine" stands for Alternatively Licensed Program for Internet News and Email.
>   Alpine is a rewrite of the [Pine Message System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pine_%28email_client%29) that adds support for Unicode and other features. Alpine is meant to be suitable for both inexperienced email users and the most demanding of power users. Alpine is developed at the University of Washington, as was Pine before it. Alpine can be learned by exploration and the use of context-sensitive help. The user interface can be customized.

If you install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) you can install alpine by doing the following:

```
sudo port install alpine
```

[image: Alpine 2.0 in action]

Comment: or if you use homebrew "brew install alpine"

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the [mail](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mail.1.html) command. It will let you send and receive email in the Terminal.

Comment: Tip: You can link to the Mac OS X man pages through developer.apple.com, the Mac's version of a command-line program doesn't always work exactly the same way as the corresponding Linux one; here's the man page for mail: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mail.1.html

Comment: Looks like the link is broken unfortunately.

Comment: Best to use the built in manual: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/reading_unix_manual_pages?language=objc

Answer (score 1):

Check the new reincarnation of the mutt - https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt